# Create smaller dataframes from one large dataframe and then pass them through different functions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and don't know where to begin. I posted a similar question earlier but was asked to give more detail.

Let's say I have a dataframe with customer responses to a survey. There are multiple question ids for the different questions, and records ids can be duplicated based on the same customer responding to multiple questions.

QuestionID 1 = What is your gender?

QuestionID 2 = How satisfied are you with this service? (0-5 point scale question)

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'RecordID':['01', '01', '02', '02', '03', '03', '04', '04'],
        'QuestionID':['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2'],
        'Response': ['male', '5', 'male', '4', 'female', '1', 'female', '1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to be able to create segments, which are essentially filtered versions of the main dataframe. My segments then are:

```
# This gives a dataframe with only female responses
female_response = df[(df['Response'] == 'female')]

# This gives a dataframe with only male responses
male_response = df[(df['Response'] == 'male')]
```

Next, I want to create a function that will do some sort of calculation for each segment based on their response. Lets say the calculation I want is "top 2 box percentage" which are customers who responded to the question "How satisfied are you with this service?" by selecting either a 4 or 5. 
The formula is: [count of those who responded with 4 or 5] / [count of everyone who responded]

```
def top2(segment):
    calc = df[(df['QuestionID'] == '2')] 
       t2 = ((calc['4'] + calc['5']) / (calc.sum())) * 100
       return top2percent
```

The function above is not correct as I keep getting errors when running it.

The last step I want is to be able to group the two segments I created, one for male respondents the other for female respondents, and then then pass all of those segments through the function.

My final result should be a new dataframe with line items that are something like:

**Male = 100%** (Out of the 2 male responses, one gave a score of 4 and the other 5)

**Female = 0%** (Out of the 2 female responses, none gave a score of 4 or 5)

My use case for this is that I have a large dataframe, that I want to create smaller segments out of (which are smaller dataframes). I then want to create different functions to pass all the segments through, in order to get calculations done per segment.

Could someone please provide a detailed solution? Apologies if this is a simple ask.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas dataframes  you need to think differenly about how to use data.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'RecordID':['01', '01', '02', '02', '03', '03', '04', '04'],
        'QuestionID':['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2'],
        'Response': ['male', '5', 'male', '4', 'female', '1', 'female', '1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert strings to numbers
df['QuestionID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['QuestionID'])

# reshape the dataframe to records flat with questions wided
df_reshaped = df.set_index(['RecordID', 'QuestionID'])['Response'].unstack()

# convert string to number for scores
df_reshaped[2] = pd.to_numeric(df_reshaped[2])

# Use groupby with aggregration to calculate percent per group.
df_result = df_reshaped.groupby(1)[2].agg(lambda x: (x.isin([4,5]).sum()/x.count()) * 100)

# show output
df_result
```

Output:

```
1
female      0
male      100
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

---

```
def get_top_2_percent(df):
    df['QuestionID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['QuestionID'])

    # reshape the dataframe to records flat with questions wided
    df_reshaped = df.set_index(['RecordID', 'QuestionID'])['Response'].unstack()

    # convert string to number for scores
    df_reshaped[2] = pd.to_numeric(df_reshaped[2])

    # Use groupby with aggregration to calculate percent per group. 

    df_result = df_reshaped.groupby(1)[2].agg(lambda x: (x.isin([4, 5]).sum()/x.count()) * 100)
    return df_result
```

Comment: This gets the desired output, but is there any way to do it using a function? That way I can apply the function to multiple data frames.